# Is there a safe vga video driver that supports high resolutions?

Tags: windows-vista, drivers, vga

My laptop is affected by the famous "[defective nVidia card](http://gizmodo.com/5653039/every-laptop-plagued-by-explode+y-nvidia-graphics-cards)" problem. It used to work fine, but since yesterday any attempt to use 3d features causes the system to BSOD (Windows) or freeze (Linux).

Actually, at first Windows wouldn't even boot anymore.

Luckily, 2d usage seems to work fine: on Linux, after disabling the nvidia proprietary driver, I'm able to work perfectly well at 1680x1050 (Compiz is disabled of course).

Likewise, on Windows, after uninstalling the nVidia driver from safe mode, I'm able to boot.

But, the "vga safe" driver that comes with Windows Vista does not support resolutions higher than 1280x1024@32 or 1400x1050@16.

Now, the question is:

- is it possible to add an additional mode to the safe vga driver, namely 1680x1050@32?
- if not, is there a third party generic vga driver that supports that resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Not safely, and it needs card support anyways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions#Modes_defined_by_VESA).